# Search a string in vim and output like grep

Tags: search, vim, grep

How can I search for a particular strings in a text file using VIM then it will output all the  lines with the instance of the search string?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Vim's built-in `global` tool. It will output the lines for all matches at the bottom of the window. An example of this is: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>g/searchterm/</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You might find it helpful to turn on line numbering if it isn't already on to get a perspective on where in the file your matches are. The command to do this is: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>set number</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Additional info can be found by running the command: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>help global</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

EDIT:

If you want to redirect the results into its own window, [`vim.wikia.com`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Redirect_g_search_output) recommends using the command sequence

```
:redir @a         redirect output to register a
:g//              repeat last global command
:redir END        end redirection
:new              create new window
:put! a           paste register a into new window
```

You can script this quite easily as a vimscript `function`. I *highly* recommend you check out the [Steve Losh - Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html) tutorial if you have never seen it to learn how to properly script Vim functions.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. And is there anyway that the it will show only the result?

Comment: @krakat I've updated with additional info. Let me know if that doesn't satisfy your question.

Answer (score 4):

There is another possibility to do it with `:g`

say you want to get all line in your current file with word `foo` :

you could type:

**`qzq:g/foo/y Z`** <kbd>Enter</kbd>

after executing the above line, those lines are stored in your register `z`. you could `"zp` to paste somewhere, or do later processing.

what does what shortly:

`qzq` : clear the `z` register

`:g/foo/y Z` : yank all matched lines to register `z`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `:g[lobal]` command in Mike's answer, here are a couple of alternatives:

- `:il[ist] foo` lists all lines containing `foo` *that don't look like comments* in the current buffer (use `:il[ist]!` if you want to match comments as well).

  When the list is displayed you can hit `<CR>` to make it disappear or hit `:` to issue Ex commands: `:5<CR>` jumps to line 5, `:5t3` copies line 5 after line 3 and so on.

  Note that the list is transient: you must re-issue the command if you want to see that list again.

  Usage:

  ```
  :il foo<CR>
  :23<CR>
  ```
- `:vim[grep] bar % | cw[indow]` populates the quickfix window with all the lines containing `bar` in the current buffer.

  Read `:h quickfix` to know how to use it. Quickly, hit `<CR>` to jump to a result, `:cn` to jump to next result, `:cp` to jump to the previous result…

  Usage:

  ```
  :vim bar % | cw<CR>
  (navigate to the result you want in the quickfix window 
   with arrows, `jk`, line numbers, search…)
  <CR>
  ```

  You can also use `:grep bar % | cw[indow]` which uses your system's `grep` instead of Vim's internal `grep`-like methods.

  Note that the content of the quickfix window won't change until the next `:vim` or `:grep` or `:make` or whatever command that manipulates the error list. It means that you can hide the quickfix window and open it back again with the same list.

Comment: Nice answer! I honestly thought the `g` stood for grep... I've updated   my answer to say global.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for, say, "qqq", I see only the lines containing said string with the command:

```
:v//d
```

"v" matches the lines *not containing* the previous search ("//") and "d" deletes them. It's a negative "g".
I get a clean view of only the lines I want. If I'm interested in a particular one I mark it with, say, "mm".
When I'm done viewing them a use "u" to undo the delete and get my file back (need not forget).
After, I move among those lines with "n" or go to the marked one with "'m".